# Javascript join() array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This might be very simple but I am trying to use the join() array in order to remove the `-` from the last item on the `days` array.

How can I do that? This is my code:

```
var days = [
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday',
  'Sunday'
];

var counter = 0;
while (counter < days.length) {
  document.write(days[counter]);
  counter++;
  days.join(' - ');
}
```

Comment: How is there a `-`? Can I see your html?

Comment: The `.join()` function returns a string. You just need `document.write(days.join(","));` and no loop.

Comment: The [default join character](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.join) is comma (,) so just `days.join()`.

Comment: @RobG but there's an space.... `join(", ")`

Comment: Who knows what the OP wants, there is no `-` either. ;-)

Comment: I do not understand what the question is or what problem you're having.  You call `days.join()` in the loop, but do nothing with the returned string so it is a pointless line of code.  Further, your question text refers to removing a `-`, but there is no such character in your code at all.

Comment: OP needs to write the group of the 7 days comma separated. He thinks that he can solve with a loop, but he discover `join()` and then he put into the loop. He doesn't need a loop.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude - that's your guess.  I think the OP should explain the question themselves rather than go off other people's guesses as to what they mean.  This question is unclear and deserves downvotes until clarified by the OP.

Comment: OP was mistaken with `-`, he should write `,`. Sometimes we need to read as psycologists. This is Internet !

Comment: When OP tries to make the while to write comma separated days, he notice that last element has a comma that he doesn't needs. This question is simplest as you want to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a loop. It's very simple:

```js
    var days = [
      'Monday',
      'Tuesday',
      'Wednesday',
      'Thursday',
      'Friday',
      'Saturday',
      'Sunday'
    ];

    document.write(days.join(", "));
```

I don't recommend the use of document.write. It's dangerous. Use DOM methods instead:

```
document.getElementById("layer").innerHTML = days.join(", ");
```

And the HTML as simple as this:

```
<div id="layer"></div>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the correct guess for what the OP is attempting to ask about (question is very unclear), but if so, why don't you put your code into a working snippet?

Comment: It's the simplest code that appears in the whole life of stackoverflow hahaha, so if you are exigent, I going to edit with a snippet, don't worry.

Comment: Just a suggestion for how to make your answer better.  I guess you don't appreciate such suggestions.

Comment: @Marcos thank you. So in this case the join() also works as a loop? And yes I know it's not recommended using document.write bla bla bla.. however this is just a test that I am writing.

Comment: Yes, join iterates all the array and makes an string with the pattern you define, in this example a comma and an space.

Comment: @Macos got it! Thank you for your help and forgive me for the question being so basic but I've just started learning js =)